# Resources on python classes

Tags: python, class

I am doing a self study of python. I just got done with inheritance. However, the book am using doesn't provide real world examples. Any recommendations for resources on python exercises on writing classes would be great. This will boost my confidence in writing useful classes.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: Dogs, Cats, and Fish are all animals. Not sure how abstract of an example you were looking for

Comment: I examples of classes that are actually useful. A class called animals with attributes Dogs, Cats, Fish is pretty useless. I need some challenging exercises on writing useful classes

Comment: @Sayse. A class to manage a zoo is good. I am not a zoo manager. To write such a class, I would need to know how to manage a zoo so I can create methods for implementing. For example I can create a class called area for computing areas of different polygons(objects) because I have information on how to compute these areas.

Comment: Great, so you said it yourself - "different polygons" so you have a base class of polygon with subclasses of different polygon types

Comment: Am looking for a scenerio where I can write a class with at least 30 lines of code-something a bit challenging .

Comment: something I am going to put some thought

Comment: You're better off just finding a 3rd party library you like on github and no doubt it wont take you long to find inheritance

Answer (score 1):

```
class Animal(object):
    voice="<Sound>"
    def speak(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__} says {self.voice}'

print(Animal().speak())

class Dog(Animal):
    voice = "Woof"

print(Dog().speak())

class Cat(Animal):
     voice = "Meow"

print(Cat().speak())
```

I guess could be considered a "real world" example ...